# Pageview hit doesn't send to Analytics 4 - React App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-analytics-4

My developer has inserted Google Tag Manager installation code to React App. Debug mode works well.

I disabled automatic tracking page views from my GA4 interface because I wan't to track page-views manually from GTM for several reasons.

BUT When I disabling this option and add in my GTM tag additional trigger (History Change), only first page-view hit is sending to GA.

I found something strange [GTAG config command with GTM ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEc3X.png) - it is pushed to dataLayer with every history change trigger.

I'm not a developer but I must to explain what is wrong with this configuration. Can you help me with brief info what should be changed?

I tried use event trigger instead of history change trigger but also, no pageview wasn't send to GA4 property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.